# Changing constexpr to consteval results in unintelligible error message in MSVC. Compiler bug or questionable code?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++20, constexpr, consteval

I have the following template / compile-time utility helper functions. It works fine in all three compilers (MSVC, GCC, clang) when everything is `constexpr`, but changing a few bits to `consteval` results in an odd error in MSVC. I want to migrate all my `constexpr` machinery to `consteval` as much as possible, and this problem is not helping.

```
#include <optional>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
 
template <auto v>
struct value_as_type {
    static constexpr auto value = v;
    using type = decltype(value);

    consteval operator type() const noexcept {
        return v;
    }
};

template <size_t First, size_t Last, typename Functor>
consteval void consteval_for([[maybe_unused]] Functor&& f) noexcept
{
    if constexpr (First < Last)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<bool, std::invoke_result_t<Functor()>>)
        {
            if (f(value_as_type<First>{}) == false)
                return;
        }
        else
            f(value_as_type<First>{});

        consteval_for<First + 1, Last>(std::forward<Functor>(f));
    }
}

template <size_t index, typename... Args>
using type_by_index = std::tuple_element_t<index, std::tuple<Args...>>;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
[[nodiscard]] consteval std::optional<size_t> index_for_type() noexcept
{
    std::optional<size_t> index;
    consteval_for<0, sizeof...(Args)>([&index](auto i) {
        if (!index) // The index of the first occurrence is stored
        {
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, type_by_index<static_cast<size_t>(i), Args... >> )
                index = static_cast<size_t>(i);
        }
    });

    return index;
}

static_assert(index_for_type<int, float, void, int, bool>() == 2);
```

The error message is:

```
<source>(52): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::optional<size_t>'        
<source>(52): note: Invalid aggregate initialization
```

I'm not seeing any aggregate initialization of the `optional` at all. And my question is: do you think it's a bug in MSVC, or is there something not right with my code?

P. S. Removing `optional` and just returning `size_t` removes the error, but I do need a way to say "the type is not present in the pack" without compilation error. `std::optional` seems the perfect fit for this semantically.

Comment: What line is the error?

Comment: @BenVoigt: the one with `static_assert`. Not helpful at all.

Comment: Have you tested the individual pieces (`value_as_type`, `consteval_for`, `type_by_index`) separately using static_assert?

Comment: `value_as_type` doesn't seem necessary or useful.  Does it work if that layer is eliminated?

Comment: It also seems like the lambda would be much simplified if the parameter type were `size_t` instead of `auto`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: that change does not make a difference - the same compilation error remains.
https://godbolt.org/z/11brj9cKx

Comment: value_as_type is quite necessary, without it I'm getting a "non-type template argument is not a constant expression" error with all three compilers here: type_by_index<static_cast<size_t>(i), Args... >>. The way I understand it, the constexpr-ness of i is lost when it's passed into a lambda as an argument, and I was originally writing this in C++17 when we didn't have template lambdas. Using `auto` and extracting the value from the argument's type (rather than the value itself) re-establishes the known-at-compile-time value. Now a more transparent way of doing this would be a template lambda.

Comment: You might look into eliminating `value_as_type` in favor of `std::integral_constant`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same error occurs with all the guts removed.

```
#include <optional>
 
[[nodiscard]] consteval std::optional<size_t> index_for_type() noexcept
{
    return 1;
}

static_assert(index_for_type() == 2);
```

This leaves me to believe that Microsoft's `std::optional` is simply not `consteval`-ready yet.

Comment: I see! It didn't occur to me this could be that simple. Looks like a compiler bug, right? Should I report this as such?

Comment: I would definitely report it.  Whether it is a compiler problem or a library problem, the Visual C++ team will figure out where the fix needs to go.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: I think I've reached the point of optimal simplification now.  There is nothing even a little bit tricky left except `consteval` and a `std::optional` return type.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Turns out it does not even have to be a template function, you still get the error.